# Can't install - Mac Bluetooth mouse and keyboard not recognized

Tags: boot, bluetooth, install

I have a 2104 iMac that I want to install elementary on.
I can boot from a USB drive and then get presented with an option to enter my wireless network password which I can do no problem - mouse and keyboard working at that point.
After doing that I can click on a drive icon on the screen which says EFI Boot (there are 2 of those icons for some reason. I have tried booting from both of them.)

It then starts to go through the elementary install process and I get presented with a screen to select my language and thats where I am dead in the water. Both mouse and keyboard are unresponsive at that point.
I really want try try elementary but am unable to.
Any ideas or help much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and had to plug in a usb keyboard to install, then once installed  bluetooth kb and mouse were recognized normally...